# Memory Usage abnormal on CentOS

Tags: linux, memory, centos

I have VMWare install CentOS 5.5 and deploy some java application.
I want to know how much memory remain, As I use command below, All memory is use.
But when I check with top command, all process use "0.0%" of memory.
So I want to know what happen? What really memory usage on this VM?

Regards,
Sathit

```
[root@web1 ~]# free -t -m
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:         16050      15911        139          0        185      15051
-/+ buffers/cache:        674      15376
Swap:        49151          0      49151
Total:       65202      15911      49290

[root@web1 ~]# cat /proc/meminfo
MemTotal:     16435972 kB
MemFree:        142484 kB
Buffers:        189632 kB
Cached:       15413188 kB
SwapCached:          0 kB
Active:        1095596 kB
Inactive:     15032400 kB
HighTotal:           0 kB
HighFree:            0 kB
LowTotal:     16435972 kB
LowFree:        142484 kB
SwapTotal:    50331604 kB
SwapFree:     50331604 kB
Dirty:              48 kB
Writeback:           0 kB
AnonPages:      525148 kB
Mapped:          31580 kB
Slab:           103152 kB
PageTables:       8840 kB
NFS_Unstable:        0 kB
Bounce:              0 kB
CommitLimit:  58549588 kB
Committed_AS:  1138116 kB
VmallocTotal: 34359738367 kB
VmallocUsed:    287644 kB
VmallocChunk: 34359450359 kB
HugePages_Total:     0
HugePages_Free:      0
HugePages_Rsvd:      0
Hugepagesize:     2048 kB

top - 10:05:02 up 7 days, 17:36,  2 users,  load average: 0.01, 0.03, 0.00
Tasks: 165 total,   1 running, 164 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
Cpu(s):  0.0%us,  0.0%sy,  0.0%ni,100.0%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,      0.0%st
Mem:  16435972k total, 16293488k used,   142484k free,   189636k buffers
Swap: 50331604k total,        0k used, 50331604k free, 15413352k cached

  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND                                                                                                   
  919 root      10  -5     0    0    0 S  0.3  0.0   0:38.53 kjournald                                                                                                 
    1 root      15   0 10368  684  572 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.75 init                                                                                                      
    2 root      RT  -5     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.58 migration/0                                                                                               
    3 root      34  19     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 ksoftirqd/0                                                                                               
    4 root      RT  -5     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.72 migration/1                                                                                               
    5 root      34  19     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 ksoftirqd/1                                                                                               
    6 root      RT  -5     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.43 migration/2                                                                                               
    7 root      34  19     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 ksoftirqd/2                                                                                               
    8 root      RT  -5     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:02.25 migration/3                                                                                               
    9 root      34  19     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 ksoftirqd/3                                                                                               
   10 root      RT  -5     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.21 migration/4                                                                                               
   11 root      34  19     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 ksoftirqd/4                                                                                               
   12 root      RT  -5     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.83 migration/5                                                                                               
   13 root      34  19     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 ksoftirqd/5                                                                                               
   14 root      RT  -5     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.40 migration/6                                                                                               
   15 root      34  19     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 ksoftirqd/6                                                                                               
   16 root      RT  -5     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.32 migration/7                                                                                               
   17 root      34  19     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 ksoftirqd/7                                                                                               
   18 root      10  -5     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.21 events/0                                                                                                  
   19 root      10  -5     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 events/1                                                                                                  
   20 root      10  -5     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 events/2                                                                                                  
   21 root      10  -5     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 events/3                                                                                                  
   22 root      10  -5     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 events/4                                                                                                  
   23 root      10  -5     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 events/5                                                                                                  
   24 root      10  -5     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 events/6                                                                                                  
   25 root      10  -5     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 events/7                                                                                                  
   26 root      10  -5     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.66 khelper
```

Comment: http://www.linuxatemyram.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think your system is problem. Can you reboot system and check again.

For my system:

```
 [root@dhcp-10-38-13-122 ~]# cat /proc/meminfo
MemTotal:        8115536 kB
MemFree:         7611020 kB
Buffers:               0 kB
Cached:            77544 kB
SwapCached:            0 kB
Active:           172188 kB
Inactive:          69860 kB
Active(anon):     164632 kB
Inactive(anon):      344 kB
Active(file):       7556 kB
Inactive(file):    69516 kB
Unevictable:           0 kB
Mlocked:               0 kB
SwapTotal:             0 kB
SwapFree:              0 kB
Dirty:                 0 kB
Writeback:             0 kB
AnonPages:        164764 kB
Mapped:             4996 kB
Shmem:               472 kB
Slab:              16004 kB
SReclaimable:       5148 kB
SUnreclaim:        10856 kB
KernelStack:        3120 kB
PageTables:          644 kB
NFS_Unstable:          0 kB
Bounce:                0 kB
WritebackTmp:          0 kB
CommitLimit:     4057768 kB
Committed_AS:     701412 kB
VmallocTotal:   251658176 kB
VmallocUsed:       34712 kB
VmallocChunk:   251554396 kB
AnonHugePages:    159744 kB
HugePages_Total:       0
HugePages_Free:        0
HugePages_Rsvd:        0
HugePages_Surp:        0
Hugepagesize:       2048 kB
[root@dhcp-10-38-13-122 ~]# free -t -m
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           7925         401        7432           0          91        7417
Swap:             0           0           0
Total:         7925         401        7432
[root@dhcp-10-38-13-122 ~]#
```

Regards,

HuyLe

Comment: I reboot it and it back to normal now. Memory usage less than 1 Gbps. I'll keep looking on it. Thanks.